# Why modified gram-schmidt is not numerical stable for giving QR fractions?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-stability

[this this a simple calculation of float point arithmetic to create right orthogonal vectors using MGS when CGS failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0JEw.jpg)

I got this demo for proving MGS is stable for giving orthogonal vectors, but why isn't the QR fraction stable?

I would like to have any opinions of it. Thank you all.